# JSR 352: Is it possible to run different partitions of the same step in the same job in Multiple JVMs?

Tags: java, websphere, jsr352, java-batch

If so, How?

I am using IBM's implementation of JSR 352 on WebSphere Liberty.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38271110/how-to-configure-run-java-batch-partitions-in-multi-jvm-in-websphere-lp)

Comment: Thank You, From what i understand this is how we'll have to configure the server. Does anything change in the java code?

Answer (score 2):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38271110/how-to-configure-run-java-batch-partitions-in-multi-jvm-in-websphere-lp) for configuration information.

As far as the programming model, one thing to consider would be the scope of your object instances, (not the batch artifacts themselves but your own application-level instances).   E.g. if you had an `@ApplicationScoped` object you could notice a difference in a single JVM, where all partitions see the same instance, vs. multiple JVMs, where you'd see one instance per JVM.

Note that the batch JobContext and StepContext instances, because they are already scoped to an individual thread, to each of the top-level thread and each partition thread, do not 
raise this concern.  They would function similarly in a single or multiple JVMs.

Comment: This might be obvious but, will using multiple JVM's improve performance? (dramatically?)

Comment: Sure, if the single JVM is maxed out it can certainly reduced the elapsed time needed to complete the job.  If the circumstances are right, then yes, the difference can be large.